# normal distribution with scipy

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone please tell me why these two functions return different results:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import math

def gaussian(x, mean, variance):
    return math.exp(-(x-mean)**2/2*variance**2)/math.sqrt(2*math.pi*variance**2)

>>> gaussian(2,0,2)
6.691511288244268e-05
>>> norm.pdf(2,0,2)
0.12098536225957168
```

Answer (score 0):

You need parentheses around `(2.0*variance**2)` (otherwise, the `variance**2` is part of the numerator instead of the denominator):

```
def gaussian(x, mean, variance):
    return math.exp(-(x-mean)**2/(2.0*variance**2))/math.sqrt(2*math.pi*variance**2)
```

With this change,

```
In [136]: norm.pdf(2,0,2)
Out[136]: 0.12098536225957168

In [137]: gaussian(2,0,2)
Out[137]: 0.12098536225957168
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @unutbu